# How to override template style in xaml

Tags: xaml, silverlight, custom-controls

In our silverlight app, we have a container view which contains a ResourceDictionary tag to a styles.xaml. Any of the views that the container calls, inherit the same styles.

The problem we have is that we have a custom control made up of a button + textbox + popup. When we use this custom control in any view, the control will work, but the appearance in incorrect because it inherits from the container style.

The custom control doesn't look right when used in these view. But if we remove the Style.xaml, the custom control looks fine.

We need to use this style template.

Is there a way to tell our custom control to not inherit from the container styles template?

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing your structure, what do you mean by "ResourceDictionary tag to a Styles.xaml"? Does that mean you have it included as a MergedDictionary in the parent container view? Are the templates within styles.xaml not defaults and just globally overriding all children elements by TargetType? It sounds like you would just need need to omit those overrides with a quick BasedOn back to a default but I'm not sure since it's not clear what the setup is currently, at least to me. :/

Comment: My container view has a MergedDictionary that points to the styles.xaml that defines a lot of the themes for the controls. When the user control views are called, they inherit their look and feel from the styles.xaml. This is fine but the custom control we added just doesn't look correct. But the custom control looks fine in other forms that don't use this styles.xaml. Is there a way to override what the styles.xaml is doing to the custom control, from the styles.xaml?

Comment: Ok sorry amigo but still having trouble visualizing what more likely the actual culprit would be. When you say it doesn't look correct, does that mean there's individual control types that don't look right like TextBox? Should I assume if you've got a custom control you've defined a ControlTemplate which inherently overrides the template of the control who would normally be receiving it's look from the style template in your styles.xaml? It sounds like in the case of for example a TextBox it would be a matter of just adding a link back to the style required via BasedOn declaration?

Comment: If it was an instance where I had it in front of me it would be much easier to give competent advice because I wouldn't think you would want to just completely omit the branded look of your stuff just for one single control?

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have a control

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyControl">
  <TextBlock Text="Small Text" FontSize="8" />
</UserControl>
```

and you are happy.

But the user puts it into this container

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
   </Style
 </Grid.Resources>
 <MyControl />
</Grid>
```

Now the textblock is going to be Red and small. This is the type of problem you are facing.

If you don't want the user of the control to override this style, you will need to be explicit in setting the colour of the textblock, e.g.

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyControl">
  <TextBlock Text="Small Text" Foreground="Black" FontSize="8" />
</UserControl>
```

ps Sorry if I got the property names wrong, it has been a while since I used WPF/Silverlight